# Android filtering pattern. WHAT IS IT?

Tags: android, design-patterns

Today I been reading the documentation of [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), and found the [getFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html#getFilter%28%29) method. In description it says:

> Returns a filter that can be used to constrain data with a filtering
>   pattern.

So what is filtering pattern? Is this some thing related to Google only, or it's source coming from computer since?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is related to `AutoCompleteTextView`s and so. When you have a `TextView` which has a list of suggestions and each time the user types in a new character it has to match any suggestion from within the `ListView`, this is implemented in a `Filter` inside the `ArrayAdapter`.

By default, the behavior is compare the entered string with any entry in the `ListView` that starts with that string. However, you might want to match also those entries that don't just begin with the entered text, but also the ones that in the middle have more words and one of them might start with this text. I guess this is what's meant by `filtering pattern`.

In this case you would overload the `performFiltering()` method of the inner `Filter` class and you would change that pattern.

Comment: I misunderstood the context. Tnx